# RStudio for Mac: "Move Focus to Source" shortcut doesn't work (?)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

The "Move Focus to Source" Shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>) doesn't seem to be working--either it does nothing or, when **RStudio** is in full-screen mode, it (annoyingly) acts as if I had just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow)</kbd> (However, *manually* clicking on "Move Focus to Source" *does* work as expected).

[This post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200660617-Gripes-and-Grumbles-about-RStudio-on-Mac-OS-X) suggests that it might be a bug. However, in contrast to the post, the other shortcuts involving control+numeral (Such as "Show History") appear to be working correctly.

So is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Also, since--as mentioned in the post--the RStudio guys `"don't recommend overriding [the keyboard shortcuts] via the Mac System Preferences"`, I'd prefer to avoid that approach (though I'm not exactly sure why it *should* be avoided--hopefully someone can shed some light on this, too).

**Set-up:**
OS X Version 10.9.3
RStudio Version 0.98.501

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Apple sets the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> shortcut to "Switch to Desktop 1". As a result, if you want to *enable* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> behavior in **RStudio** you will first have to *disable* this shortcut in the System Preferences.

Specifically, the path is:

```
System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Mission Control --> Switch to Desktop 1
```

Then, after disabling this, **RStudio**'s shortcut will work just fine.

[Note: you *could* either reassign the RStudio shortcut or the "Switch to Desktop 1" shortcut but the approach I described is definitely the most reliable since you won't have to worry about any other shortcut conflicts.]

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same problem when I use the Romaji keyboard instead of the e.g. US or US Extended keyboards.

When one of the Japanese input methods is active, ^1 is used to "Convert to related character" and ^2 is used to find a similar kanji character.

In other words, when you use multiple input methods, use the correct input method for working with RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So you had the same issue on your Mac? Good to hear that I'm not the only one. Unfortunately, I don't ever use multiple input methods so I don't think this is the issue. Nevertheless, **+1** for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment to @Steve S answer since it help me resolve the same problem but the sites don't let me. So here's an update on macOS Ventura 13.1 (the OS has changed a little since the question was first asked)

To disable system shortcuts `Ctrl+1`

```
# on the top menu # click the apple icon # then follow
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Mission Control
  -> expand "Mission Control" item -> Disable "Switch to Desktop 1"
```